# bind a jquery plugin to ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I've used sortable/portlet jquery ui plugin on my website. I load some boxes after the page is loaded via ajax. but they don't look like the boxes appears at the page load time. I know the problem loading via ajax and bind issue. But how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: $(".column").sortable({
                          connectWith: ".column",
                          cursor: 'crosshair'
                       
});

Comment: Put that code after completion of your ajax.

Comment: but there are some boxes are load before ajax,ajax add some new ones and the ajax is execute on click event. If I put it after ajax the previous boxes won't be styled.

Answer (score 0):

You're ajax call has a success method which you can use to bind to elements that have been dynamically added.

For example you could do

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
   $(".column").sortable({ connectWith: ".column", cursor: 'crosshair' });
  }
});
```